# Using DOM HTML to parse html and return href

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, domparser

Okay, so I am trying to parse html with DOM HTML PHP parse and return an img tag, which I will then insert into my html and link back to the source. 
In this case I want to use the top image of the day on reddi.com/r/Earthporn....as you can imagine I have to parse through an abundance of tags....
Here's a screen shot so you know which one I'm trying to tackle (it's highlighted):
[image: Here's a screen shot so you know which one I'm trying to tackle (it's highlighted)] I want to parse using that span tag possibly- because I always want the 1st true image, but the a tag isn't it's child, and the div class that it is a child of keeps changing because sometimes they have other content above it.

And my code looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/top/?sort=top&t=day')->plaintext;

$element = $html->find('div[class=thing id-t3_22ds3k odd link]/text()', );
echo'<img src='.$element[0]->src.'/>';

}

?>
```

Which just returns this on my webpage:
[image: php output]

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm kinda new to this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is PHP installed and working at your hosting or PC as it does not seem to be running PHP given its returning the raw file to you? Also is the portion of HTML that you wish to read present when you right click the page and select view source code? If its not you will not be able to obtain it via `file_get_html`.

Comment: Sorry it did but I forgot to hit enter one more space down so it would show. This gets the html from another web url, which is present (my screenshot at the top shows it) I'm trying to figure out how to access that a.thumbnail.may-blank href, but since all of the images have that tag, it becomes difficult, they are also all inside of a div and then in that a class.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @puppies_pidgeons That is incorrect. On the image you show us, you're using most likely firebug which also gathers rendered content that doesn't show on the HTML source code which are usually generated via JavaScript and other methods **that's why you must be sure it shows on the source code instead if you want to use `file_get_html`.**

Comment: @Prix I have updated the screenshot at top to be the actual source code instead of firebug

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible? As others were hinting at, it looks as though the PHP code is being parsed as HTML instead of processed as PHP...